# Partition Function Question

Tags: statistical-mechanics, gas

I've been looking at calculating the Internal energy of a non-isothermic van de Waals gas, and in doing so have been researching the free energy and hence the partition function necessary to calculate that.

The problem is that the partition function cannot be computed in any formulae that I have come across due to the very large value of $N$ being ~ 1e^20 particles. This means that the free energy and hence the internal energy cannot be calculated, and I cannot solve my problem.

For example using the formula:$$Z = \frac{V^N}{N!{h^{3N}}}{\left({\frac{2{\pi}m}{\beta}}\right)}^{\frac{3N}{2}}$$

There are several incomputable terms which must be approximated. The term $N!$ can be approximated using Stirling's approximation but even in that form it still contains a term that is to the power of N just like many other terms, which cannot be computed and must be further approximated. For example, approximating the term $h^{3N}$, it can be seen to approach zero when N approaches $\infty$. This term alone for a large number of particles N ~ 1e^20 seems to completely break the equation and the same for the terms ${\left({\frac{2{\pi}m}{\beta}}\right)}^{\frac{3N}{2}}$ and $V^N$ when approximated.

My question is how do scientists, engineers, mathematicians, etc, actually compute this partition function for a large number of particles, I have seen that it is possible in many papers but I have never seen a successful substitution of values, and have clearly never been able to successfully complete it myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, any *useful* thermodynamic quantities involve taking the natural log of $Z$ rather than the absolute value of $Z$ itself.  For example the Helmholtz free energy is
$$F=-kT\ln Z$$
and internal energy is
$$U=kT^2\frac{\partial\ln Z}{\partial T}$$
It's fine that $Z$ is usually incommputably large.  It is a measure of the number of microstates available to a system, and for most systems, this *should* be an incredibly large number (practically infinite).  It must be this way if things like the second law of thermodynamics are to be obeyed!

Comment: Hi @Garf, I forgot to mention I have tried doing this directly but all calculators have rejected it for being too large, any suggestions? I could try the approximation Z ~ infinity and then lnZ is infinity but then F is infinity which is untrue.

Comment: I don't think you should try to evaluate $Z$.  Do some algebra first and evaluate $\ln Z$.

Comment: So for your example, $$\ln Z=N\ln V+\frac{3N}{2}\ln\left(\frac{2\pi m}{\beta}\right)-\ln N! - 3N\ln h$$and you can use Stirling's approximation to make $\ln N!\approx N\ln N-N$

Comment: hi @Garf, sorry to bother you, but I am struggling to calculate the partial derivative $\frac{{\partial}{{\ln}{Z}}}{{\partial}{T}}$, do you have any idea how this can be solved or simplified into a non-derivative term?

Comment: Split up the logs fully and note that everything except $\beta=1/kT$ is constant:
$$\ln Z=\frac{3N}{2}\ln(T)+\text{other things}\;\Rightarrow\;\frac{\partial\ln Z}{\partial T}=\frac{3N}{2T}$$  You then obtain the hopefully familiar result that $$U=\frac{3}{2}NkT$$  Note this isn't the internal energy of a vdW gas, and your partition function is not one for a vdW gas either.  It is instead the partition function for an ideal gas.

Comment: Hi @Garf, I have done the research and cannot seem to find a partition function which I can solve in the partial derivate, my mathematical abilities are just not quite good enough, regardless can you recommend the correct partition function for a vdW gas as I have seen many. Thankyou

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waals_equation#Statistical_thermodynamics_derivation -- -- here's what Wikipedia says. The trouble is if you want exact you would need to consider every possible pair-wise Coulombic attraction, which just isn't feasible, so you're going to have to make some approximations / assumptions along the way. I can imagine there are varieties out there. I suggest opening another question if you want to ask more about it, as there's not much space for discussion to be had in the comments here.

Comment: Thank you, this has seemed to of worked.